# azure: "Structure needs cleaning error" on attached disk

Tags: azure

I followed this process here closely - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal

However, whenever I seem to make changes to the attached disk from another machine, I invariably end up with the error "Structure needs cleaning." on other machines with the attached disk when doing any type of disk operation on that drive.

I've confirmed that my /etc/fstab file is correct and that the various commands on the page respond with expected values.

I am now getting it non deterministically as I use the drive.  It's a serious issue and means I can't use the attached disk.

Running fstrim doesn't help, but also creates the error.

I am using the latest azure ubuntu 18.04.5 image.

Rebooting the server seems to make the problem temporarily go away until I do some other type of disk operation on another server.

Comment: I think you can't share a "normal" data disk directly from two vms. But maybe, if it fits your requirements, this could be of help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disks-shared#linux

Comment: Does this help you? https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4b47r2/has_anyone_ever_gotten_structure_needs_cleaning/ and a post from someone who used that fix and wrote about his situation: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2147027-linux-structure-needs-cleaning-error

Comment: Are you using that disk with samba?

Comment: Yes, azure uses blockstore as it's backing and has written a custom SMB driver.  It's a new feature announced just this July.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-azure-shared-disks-and-new-azure-disk-storage-enhancements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure you have several storage options.

Focusing on those related to block storage, you also have several options.

On one hand, you have "normal" data disks, Azure-managed data disks that you can attach to your virtual machine as boot disks or for additional storage. This type of disk is the one described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal) that you followed.

But these types of disks, AFAIK, by themselves, cannot be directly shared by multiple virtual machines at the same time without interference between them. The problem you are experimenting have to do with this. In essence, with the `Structure needs cleaning.` message, the OS is telling you that the disk is corrupted, and this corruption have to do with being used by several VMs at the same time.

If you need this sharing capability, as [you indicated in your comments](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-azure-shared-disks-and-new-azure-disk-storage-enhancements/), Azure also offers [shared disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disks-shared#linux) based in advanced disks capabilities like [SCSI Persistent Reservations](https://www.t10.org/members/w_spc3.htm).

You can [enable the feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared-enable?tabs=azure-cli) and create disks of this type if you need to.

Please, be aware that this shared disk approach has some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disks-shared#limitations).

Also, it is well suited for highly demand and high performance resource [scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disks-shared#sample-workloads) like database clusters.

But, by your comments, if I understand you correctly, you only need the ability to connect to persistent storage with Samba. If that is the case, Azure offers another block storage type of storage, based internally in its blob storage solution, named [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction).

Azure Files basically provides a typical shared file system, accessible via `smb` or `nfs`.

If Azure Files fits your needs, you only need to set up a storage account with this service enabled and follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) which will drive you through the process of how to use it with Linux systems.

In addition, the Azure Files approach will offer you a simpler and cheaper solution than the shared disk one.

Comment: @Blaze Does the answer make sense to you? I understand that I am not actually providing a solution for the disk corruption problem. By searching on Google, you can find multiple information related to how to solve the problem. But even if you fix it, the solution will be temporary, as soon as you connect the disk to another virtual machine, the disk will be damaged again. This is what I am trying to explain. I am also trying to provide you with alternatives that, for your feedback, I think may meet your needs. Please, if you consider it appropriate, I can expand the answer in some aspect.

Comment: Yes, thank you!   I think perhaps they should mention this on the page.  The one I linked to mentions you can mount existing disks which lead me to believe this was viable.  It is also the same process you use when creating disks via the portal.

Comment: You're welcome Blaze. And, I agree with you, they should have specified it better in the post. I am very happy to know that the answer was helpful.